# want date start to end in while loop in one array for one room id

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql, json

i am looking to show on calendar the unavailable dates of hotel rooms , that are alredy booked, but i am only able to show one date, but i want to show all dates booked on that month liked, one from 20-25, second 29-31...

```
echo $query = "SELECT * FROM booking_request where room_id = 1' '<br>' ";
$result = $db->query($query);
        if( $result -> num_rows > 0 ) {
            while( $row = $result-> fetch_assoc() )
            {
            echo $name = $row['getaway_name']." <br>";
            echo $start = $row['check_in_date']." <br>";
            echo $end = $row['check_out_date']." <br>";
            $cp = array();
            $arr1 = range(strtotime($row['check_in_date']),strtotime($row['check_out_date']), "86400");

            array_walk_recursive($arr1, function(&$element) { $element = date("d-n-Y", $element); });
           print_r ($arr1); 
            }
```

i am getting all the dates in

```
Array ( 
[0] => 15-5-2016 
[1] => 16-5-2016 
[2] => 17-5-2016 
[3] => 18-5-2016 
[4] => 19-5-2016 
[5] => 20-5-2016 
) 

Array ( 
[0] => 29-5-2016 
[1] => 30-5-2016 
[2] => 31-5-2016 
)
```

like this from while loop, i want this in single array ..

Comment: try using array_merge($a1,$a2);

Comment: when i am trying using array_merge that i am unable to get complete dates between like 20-24 o/p- 20,21,22,23,24..

Answer (score 0):

Arrays always have keys, whether you want them or not. Even a simple `array('15-5-2016', '16-5-2016');` will be `array([0] => '15-5-2016', [1] => '16-5-2016');`. That being said, your array does start with 0, and not with 1.

If you want only values then you have to use loop(foreach, I recommend) where you want to use this array. So you'll get values from array.

Comment: in my project i have one room id, that have booking from 2-5, and 7-9 ,10-12, i want to fetch all the dates between them , and want to show on calendar that this dates are already booked, by doing above code, i am able to show only  last entry in calendar that are booked,

Comment: Because `$arr1` got override every time in while loop. Print `$arr1` outside the loop, you'll got only last entry.

Comment: Define `$arr1` as `array` type and store all values of  `$arr1` in array from while loop as `$arr1[] += $arr1;` at the end of while loop.

Answer (score 0):

First merage array all like this

```
 $arr1[] = range(strtotime($row['check_in_date']),strtotime($row['check_out_date']), "86400");
```

after foreach loop of array.

Comment: i tried your solution but i i am unale to find all dates of that booked for room id.

Answer (score 0):

I've edited my previous answer and used the info from your arrays.

This is the example for your array: [New example](http://img.prntscr.com/img?url=http://i.imgur.com/oMeLKGr.png)!

```
<?php
$date = date("Y-m-d");
$time=strtotime($date);
$month=date("m",$time);
$year=date("Y",$time);
$end = $year. "-" . $month . "-" . date('t', strtotime($date));
$datebooked=array ('2016-05-15', '2016-05-16', '2016-05-17', '2016-05-18', '2016-05-19', '2016-05-20');
$datebooked1=array('2016-05-29', '2016-05-30', '2016-05-31');
$datesbooked=array_merge($datebooked, $datebooked1);

?>
<table>
<tr>
<?php while(strtotime($date) <= strtotime($end)) {
    $day_num = date('d', strtotime($date));
    $day_name = date('l', strtotime($date));
    $date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($date)));
    if(in_array("".$year."-".$month."-".$day_num, $datesbooked)){
        echo "<td style='color:red;'>$day_num <br/> $day_name</td>";
    }else{
        echo "<td style='color:blue;'>$day_num <br/> $day_name</td>";
    }
}
?>
</tr>
</table>
```

You'll have to change variables of the range arrays.
Use something like this:

```
$count=0;
while($count!==$result->num_rows()){
$count++;
${arr.$count}=range(strtotime($row['check_in_date']),strtotime($row['check_out_date']), "86400");;
}
```

You can then read each array as: $arr1, $arr2, $arr3

Then as the line 9 in my code:

```
$datesbooked=array_merge($arr1, $arr2, $arr3);
```

Comment: in my code, i am trying to fetch the start and end date for one room id from the datebase, then it is everytime giving the values in the array, within same variable..

Comment: Try using my code and change array variables with ${'varname'} syntax:

Comment: $count=0;
while($count!==$result->num_rows()){
 $count++;
 ${arr.$count}=range(strtotime($row['check_in_date']),strtotime($row['check_out_date']), "86400");;
}

Use something like this to change the variables.

I will add this to my answer to make it more clear.

Comment: error is coming Call to undefined method mysqli_result::num_rows()

Comment: Sorry. Remove the () after the num_rows.

Comment: constant arr - assumed 'arr' in C:\xampp\htdocs\ajax_cal\Calendar.php on lin         echo $category = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'category'))  .'<br>'; 
if( $category != 0 ){
    
echo $query = "SELECT * FROM booking_request where resort_id = '$category' '<br>' ";
$result = $db->query($query);
        $count=0;
        while($count!==$result->num_rows){
        $count++;
        ${arr.$count}=range(strtotime($row['check_in_date']),strtotime($row['check_out_date']), "86400");;
        }
 $datesbooked=array_merge($arr1, $arr2, $arr3);
 echo $datesbooked;

Comment: $datesbooked=array_merge($arr1, $arr2, $arr3);
note there has to be 3 rows in mysql select for you to manually input arr1, arr2 etc. Use as many as the num_rows is. Also make sure the $count while is outside of any other while. Or you could use foreach instead.

Comment: thanks for help, i have applied foreach loop to get the value, in while loop, and get same result, thanks

Comment: hi,on booked dates how to show user complete inforamtion from database on mousehover on date///

Comment: i got the booked dates in calendar now, iwant to show user info lijke 12-15 booked by diff user, 17-19 booked by other user, on mouse hover info show show to user....

Comment: Do you have the info stored in the same table in your database?

Comment: yes i am storing the info on same table booking_request, that we are booking on user request, now i want to show user info on calendar booked  dates, like name, mobile no etc...

Comment: like 20-24 booked_id 1 , like 20-27 booked id 2, then by fetching acc to id want to show info of that id on mouse over booked dates..